# Safari Windows vs Safari Mac

Tags: web-development, macos, browser, safari

Does the Windows version render stuff differently then the Mac version of Safari? Our website has over 34% traffic from Safari Browsers. Just wondering as we're mostly a Windows shop.

Comment: i really can't see why this should be closed - it's a clear question, depending to web-development which can definetely be answered.

Comment: What user agent strings do you see in your logs? e.g. are these iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad users accessing your site? They will all report as Safari also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the rendereing-engine is the same, so is looks the same. what *could* be different are form-elements without css-styles - those will be displayed in the operating-systems look-and-feel... (you havn't posted a link to your site, so you're the only one who could find out)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge they do not.  They are both based off of the webkit browsing engine.  Google Chrome also uses this engine.

Comment: That's all great news. Glad to hear just OS specific will not display excaulty the same.